# Can I define two custom html elements with customElements.define?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element, native-web-component

I have written a class that extends HTMLElement and are ready to bind the element to the Dom with customElements.define. I thought it was possible to create as many elements as needed but somehow this is not the case.

```
    let but = factory.createButtonElement('./img/question2.png');
    let butt = factory.createButtonElementt('./img/question2.png');
    customElements.define('sel-but', but);
    customElements.define('sel-butt', butt);
    /**
     * Also tried this
     * customElements.whenDefined('sel-but').then(()=>{
     *  customElements.define('sel-butt', butt);
     * })
     */
```

And my HTML looks have these two elements

```
    <sel-but></sel-but>
    <sel-butt></sel-butt>
```

The error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this constructor has already been used with this registry
```

How will can I get two buttons up on the screen?

Thanks

Comment: Can you make it a working SO snippet: [ < > ] on the edit toolbar , including your factory function

Answer (score 2):

Make it 2  defines, that **extend**:

```js
class ButElement extends HTMLElement {
     ...
}

customElements.define("sel-but", class extends ButElement{});
customElements.define("sel-butt", class extends ButElement{});


// I don't know your factory functions... something like this:
let klass = factory.createButtonElement('./img/question2.png');
customElements.define("sel-but", class extends klass );
customElements.define("sel-butt", class extends klass );
```

Answer (score 0):

Both factory method are pointing to the same class. And because the CustomElementRegistry can only hold one constructor it returns the error.